# Is there a way to make the hover area larger than the image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, hover

I was wondering if there is a way to make the hover area bigger than the image?

For example, I have an image that is 72px x 61px and when I hover over it, it changes to a different image. What I would like to know is if I can hover outside the image but still trigger the change in the image.

Sorry if this is confusing, I tried to post an image but since I just signed up I am not able to.

Comment: Yes it is possible, just have a parent element with the image inside by larger and have a hover action on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example, just `hover` in the `gray` colored region

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 60px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.outer:hover>img {
  content: url('http://docs.gimp.org/en/images/filters/examples/color-taj-sample-colorize.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <img src="http://goo.gl/7VYJyX" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Put it in a container (`<div>`, `<a>`, whatever), add padding to the container (to increase the area).

If what you're doing is in JS, attach the hover handler to the container instead of the image.

If you're doing CSS, something like this should be helpful:

```
.container:hover img{
  /* styles for img when .container is hovered*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are going for. her is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pdjoh1dy/1/
HTML

```
 <div id="hover-example">
     <div id="img-holder">
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#hover-example{width: 500px; height: 500px; border-style: solid;}
#img-holder{margin: 25%; width: 50%; height: 50%; background-color: blue;}
#hover-example:hover > #img-holder{
    background-color: red;
    margin: 10%; 
    width: 80%; 
    height: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also set the image to `display: block` and add `padding`, if it does not mess with your layout.